# How to set a Gitlab server only available on your local network?

Tags: git, raspberry-pi, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

I'm currently setting up a Gitlab instance on my Raspberry Pi, I want it to only be available through the network is currently connected to (So lan only basically). But if I leave the EXTERNAL_URL at the default https://example.gitlab.com, during setup it says `Gitlab was unable to detect a valid hostname for your instance. Please configure a URL for you Gitlab instance by setting 'external_url' configuration in the /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file.` But if I set the external URL to the devices local IP, and then run reconfigure, it says `There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure: Gitlab external URL must include a schema and GQDN, e.g. http://gitlab.example.com/`.

Is there a way I can configure Gitlab to only run locally of the network? (Lan only?) I'd think it would be pretty simple, but I can't find any Gitlab documentation regarding this.

Comment: Ar you only providing the IP? Maybe gitlab requires the protocol to be defined. try adding `http://` before IP

Comment: @DTul Trying that gives me the same error `There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure: Gitlab external URL must include a schema and GQDN, e.g. http://gitlab.example.com/` Any other ideas?